# Writing in file C++

Tags: c++, file

How can I write into a specific location of a file? My file contains the following info:

```
100 msc
```

I want to update it as:

```
100 10 20 34 32 43 44
```

So I want to skip `100` and overwrite `msc` with the new input array.

Answer (score 2):

The best way that I know of is to read in the complete contents of the file, and then use some string manipulations to overwrite what you need.  Then you can write back the modified information to the same file, overwriting its contents.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand that you can't modify files like that.
You can but its a little more tricky than that (as you need to have space).

So what you have to do is read the file and write it into a new file then re-name the file to the original.

Since you know exactly where to read to and what to insert do that first.

```
void copyFile(std::string const& filename)
{
    std::ifstream    input(filename.c_str());
    std::ofstream    output("/tmp/tmpname");


    // Read the 100 from the input stream
    int x;
    input >> x;


    // Write the alternative into the output.
    output <<"100 10 20 34 32 43 44 ";

    // Copies everything else from
    // input to the output.
    output << input.rdbuf();
}

int main()
{
    copyFile("Plop");
    rename("Plop", "/tmp/tmpname");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ktodisco's method works well, but another option would be to open the file with read/write permissions, and move the file position pointer to the write place in the buffer, and then just write what you need to. C++ probably has specifics to do this, but do it cleanly with just the C `stdio` library. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("myfile", "r+");
    /* skip ahead 4 characters from the beginning of file */
    fseek(f, 4, SEEK_SET);
    /* you could use fwrite, or whater works here... */
    fprintf(f, "Writing data here...");

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use these as references:
 - [fseek](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/)
 - [fwrite](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/)

Hope I helped!

**== EDIT ==**

In C++ the `iostream` class seems to be able to do all of the above. See: [iostream](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/iostream/)

Comment: This works if you want to overwrite the existing data in the file.  However, if you want to insert new data into the middle of an existing file you'll have to go with ktodisco's approach.  I can't tell what the OP is really trying to do but it looks like it might be the latter.

Comment: @Sean I'm assuming that the OP just wants to overwrite it (since he says: `I want to skip 100 and OVERWRITE "msc" with the new input array`) If it's the other case, then yes, ktodisco's method is probably best.

Comment: Yeah, but "msc" is only three characters.  If he writes more than that then he'll write over what comes after that.  That's why it looks to me like he wants to insert and would need to read the file in first.

Comment: @Sean Well, from the (lack of) context given by the OP it is hard to be certain. In the end, both answers work for their given purpose, so the OP will just have to choose the one that suits him best... :)